# Asus Eee PC doesn't have "OS Installation" or Boot to in BIOS Menu?

Tags: bios

I'm trying to reformat an Eee PC that only has external USB slots, no disc drive, and I can't find out how to install anything else on it as far as OS' go because it won't load from USB - The BIOS menu doesn't show any way to boot from USB.

Anyone able to help me?

I know this question isn't specifically for installing Ubuntu, but its more than anything a general question to installing another OS so maybe you could still

Comment: Take the Drive out put into another computer install from there put the drive back.. easy :)

Comment: Also, In case that the eeePC sees the normal hard drive go to HDD drives in BIOS and select USB something or other, instead of the regular drive first, save, restart then it should boot from your SD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you will need to create a bootable USB-drive with a Live installation of Ubuntu (or some other Linux).

**HOWTO: Create a bootable USB-drive in Ubuntu**

Just download the image you want from [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download), launch '[Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/usb-creator-gtk/)' (already installed by default) and choose to install the image you just downloaded onto a drive of your choice. This drive can be a CD, a DVD, a USB or an SD card. Be aware that any data stored on the drive you choose will be erased.

You will have to provide your root password during the installation, in order to give the installer the necessary permissions required to write a boot-loader onto the drive.

You can also choose to create a persistence file, which will allow you to save settings between sessions.

[image: Startup Disk Creator]

**HOWTO: Create a bootable USB-drive in Windows**

There are a number of tools available in Windows to create bootable media, but my personal favorite is [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It's pretty straightforward, and it can even download the appropriate Live CD image for you.

[image: UNetbootin on Windows]

Once you have successfully created a bootable USB-drive, plug it into the computer you wish to install Ubuntu on and (re-)start it. On the Asus EeePC line of computers, you can enter the boot-menu by pressing the Esc-key when you start the computer. Which exact key is used for this differs between brands.

That should be all you need to do to create and boot into a Live USB session on a computer without an optical drive.

Answer (score 1):

To boot from USB on the Eee, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the BIOS screen to get the boot prompt.

If you are having problems using the image on the usb stick, you'll want to check the .iso you downloaded is complete by checking the md5sum (see here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Answer (score 0):

I install OSes on my Eee PC using an external cd/dvd drive (usbconnection).

I have never installed an OS from a pen drive but here is the process:

First insert the bootable pen drive to you Eee PC (Essential, make sure you do it before booting, otherwise it won't appear on the bios settings).

Now enter the Bios setup by pressing Del (or F2 depending on your BIOS)

Navigate to Boot device priority and make "USB Devices/External Device" your primary boot device.

Save and Exit.

Reboot.

Happy hacking !!